# Adding block and creating unique class ID

Tags: blocks, cms, widget

we add blocks to cms/blocks and pages using this convention

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="my_block1"}}
{{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="my_block2"}}
```

Now recently I had to specificall set the CSS styling to my_block1 (or my_block2 for that matter) when I saw that these blocks all have the same CSS CLASS `widget widget-static-block`. I was hoping to see something `widget widget-static-block my_block1`

**My question:** Now how can we add the block ID to the class? And would this not be a good idea to add to Magento core?

And as a side question: what exactly is the difference between the two cms/block calls? (1 widget and 1 block both under cms)

So the result would be something like `widget widget-static-block my_block1` or `cms_block my_block1`

ps. I do understand there may be some caveats - because you might not want to always expose the exact block ID in your HTML. But I can imagine that for instance the name="" or as="" statement could in that case function as the name and it can be passed via the cms/block call and added as a CLASS element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the template `cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml` to your theme and replace the original content

```
<div class="widget widget-static-block"><?php echo $this->getText(); ?></div>
```

with

```
<div class="widget widget-static-block <?php echo $this->getBlockId();?>"><?php echo $this->getText(); ?></div>
```

As for your side question, the only difference is that you can specify a template when using the widget approach. So you can have some kind of markup around the block text. Just like the template used in your example.

Comment: And would this be an idea for Magento core?

Comment: I'm not in a position to say that.

Comment: just oto be clear this is for `cms/widget_block` only?